# What does "leaves you wanting more" mean?

Tags: phrases

For eg. Sony Z1s: It's Got the Look, But Leaves You Wanting More.

Comment: This question belongs on our [sister site for learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), but is now too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

When you're done using it, you are "left" in a state of dissatisfaction - you want more after you have gotten all that this thing has to give. It's saying "this isn't necessarily horrible, but it's not as good as I hoped for." On the bright side, what you did get was pleasant, even though it wasn't enough.

Comment: I've seen some use this line with a different (more or less in an opposite sense) meaning. For eg. _Excellent food, leaves you wanting more_ means that food is so good that you want more.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BigBoss comment, and I know the expression *Always leave them wanting more* is also used in the show business, to recommend that when the audience is responding positively to your performance you should not exhaust your repertoire in that occasion but rather end your show before the spectators become completely satisfied, so that they will probably be eager to attend your next show.